# R list extraction with duplicates

Tags: r, list

I have a nested R list that looks like:

```
> myList
$name
[1] "John"                         "Sue"
[3] "Bob"                          "Mark"      

$value
[1] "25" "37" "42" "39"

$boolean
[1] "T" "T" "F" "F"

$name
[1] "Joe" "Mary"           

$value
[1] "78" "91"

$boolean
[1] "T"  "T"
```

I am trying to extract all entries that belong to `$name`, but since I have multiple `$name`'s, `myList$name` only returns the first one:

```
> myList$name
[1] "John"                         "Sue"
[3] "Bob"                          "Mark"
```

How can I return:

```
[1] "John"                         "Sue"                         "Bob"
[3] "Mark"                         "Joe"                         "Mary"
```

Comment: Note that the list in this example is not nested. If it can be avoided, using the same names is not recommended. In some circumstances, you can use `make.unique`  to output unique names. It will append integers to identical names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grepl` to get the position of the *name* elements and then extract:

```
myList <- list(name = c(1,2), value = c(2,3), name = c(4,5))

unlist(myList[grepl('name', names(myList))], use.names = F)
# [1] 1 2 4 5
```

Or simply:

```
unlist(myList[names(myList) == 'name'], use.names = F)
# [1] 1 2 4 5
```

Comment: Use the `unlist` part as @lmo's comment.